# IO Error during Oracle ORDS uninstallation

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-ords

I am trying to uninstall ORDS from my server, but it is not working correctly. I am trying to uninstall it so I can reattempt the installation.

The uninstallation is failing with the following error:

```
Enter the name of the database server [dbname]:dbname
Enter the database listen port [1521]:1521
Enter 1 to specify the database service name, or 2 to specify the database SID [1]:1
Enter the database service name [servicename]:servicename
Requires to login with administrator privileges to verify Oracle REST Data Services schema.

Enter the administrator username:sys as sysdba
Enter the database password for sys as sysdba:
Confirm password:
Mar 24, 2020 3:16:47 PM oracle.dbtools.rt.config.setup.SchemaSetup verifyDBAUserConnection
WARNING: Failed to connect to user sys as sysdba jdbc:oracle:thin:@//dbname:1521/servicename 
IO Error: Unknown host specified
```

How can I correct this error to uninstall ORDS?

Comment: check this out https://github.com/martindsouza/docker-oracle-ords/issues/12

Comment: check ords_params.properties file and make sure that `db.hostname` parameter is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to ORDS/params folder and look in ords_params.properties file and make sure that db.hostname is correct. Should be the fully-qualified name of your server

Comment: I was able to uninstall it by modifying the ords_params.properties file. The hostname was not correct.